# Why I failed removing 'resize' event on window?

Tags: javascript, html, events

There is a div element in my page. Here are the functionalities I would like it to have:

1. Fill out the browser window, that is, maximized, after it's clicked
2. After it's maximized, the div element remains maximized when the browser window size changes.
3. When it's maximized, clicking on it restores the div to its original size before it was maximized.

To implement the second point, I registered a resize event on the window to maintain the maximized state. The resize event is removed when it comes to the third point. However, it seems that the resize event failed to be removed because when I adjust the browser window, the div element is maximized again.
Can anybody tell me what happens underneath the hood?

http://jsbin.com/pokirokahe/edit?html,output

```html
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    div {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      border: 2px solid blue;
      background: gray;
    }
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div></div>
  <script>
    var domDiv = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
    var maximized = false;
    var originSize = {};

    originSize.w = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(domDiv, null).width);
    originSize.h = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(domDiv, null).height);
    domDiv.addEventListener("click", function() {
      if (!maximized) {
        fullfill();
        maximized = true;
        console.log("maximized true, adding event listener");
        window.addEventListener("resize", fullfill);
      } else {
        this.style.width = originSize.w + "px";
        this.style.height = originSize.h + "px";
        console.log("maximized false, removing event listener");
        window.removeEventListener("resize", fullfill);
        maximized = false;
      }

      function fullfill() {
        var screensize = getViewportSize();
        console.log(screensize.w + " " + screensize.h);
        var divBorder = {
          top: parseFloat(getComputedStyle(domDiv, null).borderTopWidth),
          bottom: parseFloat(getComputedStyle(domDiv, null).borderBottomWidth),
          left: parseFloat(getComputedStyle(domDiv, null).borderLeftWidth),
          right: parseFloat(getComputedStyle(domDiv, null).borderRightWidth)
        };

        domDiv.style.width = screensize.w - divBorder.left - divBorder.right + "px";
        domDiv.style.height = screensize.h - divBorder.top - divBorder.bottom + "px";
      }
    });

    function getViewportSize(w) {
      w = w || window;

      if (w.innerWidth != null) return {
        w: w.innerWidth,
        h: w.innerHeight
      };
      var d = w.document;
      if (document.compatMode == "CSS1Compat")
        return {
          w: d.documentElement.clientWidth,
          h: d.documentElement.clientHeight
        };
      return {
        w: d.body.clientWidth,
        h: d.body.clientHeight
      };
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everytime you trigger `click` event, you defined a function named `fullfill`, so the function `fullfill` your `addEventListener` is not equal to the one you remove.
If you want your web run correctly, you should define the function named `fullfill` out of your `click` eventListner.

Answer (score 0):

well i think it is best to use css in this case, since you need the div to be maximized and get the browser's size, use the position absolute or fixed to the div and give it height:100% , width:100% it will re-size automatically with the browser and it will save you the hassle of JS events.

Comment: But I still want to know what's wrong with my event?